# Edditing updater-script

Tags: builds

In [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2559601) thread, #6 post jellopuddingstick said that he could remove the check on updater-script in order to flash a rom which doesnt fit with build.prop .

For example, this is my updater script I found in meta inf/com/google/android:

```
assert(getprop("ro.product.device") == "thea" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "thea" || 
    getprop("ro.product.device") == "thea_umtsds" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "thea_umtsds" || 
    getprop("ro.product.device") == "thea_ds" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "thea_ds" || 
    getprop("ro.product.device") == "XT1072" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "XT1072" || 
    getprop("ro.product.device") == "XT1078" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "XT1078" || 
    getprop("ro.product.device") == "XT1079" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "XT1079" || abort("E3004: This package is for device: thea,thea_umtsds,thea_ds,XT1072,XT1078,XT1079; this device is " + getprop("ro.product.device") + "."););
ui_print("Target: motorola/lineage_thea/thea:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.011/c397c2b19d:userdebug/test-keys");
ifelse(is_mounted("/system"), unmount("/system"));
package_extract_dir("install", "/tmp/install");
set_metadata_recursive("/tmp/install", "uid", 0, "gid", 0, "dmode", 0755, "fmode", 0644);
set_metadata_recursive("/tmp/install/bin", "uid", 0, "gid", 0, "dmode", 0755, "fmode", 0755);
mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system", "/system", "");
run_program("/tmp/install/bin/backuptool.sh", "backup");
unmount("/system");
show_progress(0.750000, 0);
ui_print("Patching system image unconditionally...");
block_image_update("/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system", package_extract_file("system.transfer.list"), "system.new.dat.br", "system.patch.dat") ||
  abort("E1001: Failed to update system image.");
show_progress(0.020000, 10);
mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system", "/system", "");
run_program("/tmp/install/bin/backuptool.sh", "restore");
unmount("/system");
show_progress(0.050000, 5);
package_extract_file("boot.img", "/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/boot");
show_progress(0.200000, 10);
set_progress(1.000000);
```

How exactly would I need to edit this in order to not scramble it up?

Comment: Remove the whole assert block, up to the first `ui_print` command. However, ignoring asserts means you are at your own risk if you flash it on an incompatible device/recovery.

Comment: As Andy said, don't remove this check. We've had several questions before from people who removed the check, thinking that meant they could install a ROM on the wrong device, and then bricked their phone. The check isn't what stops the ROM working: being for the wrong phone is what stops it working, sometimes permanently.